# Visual Studio Cloud Credentials unsupported browser

Tags: visual-studio

Im trying to reenter my credentialz in Visual Studio Cloud Explore, but everytime i try to follow the reenter credentialz link i get the same error:

[image]

I have tried updating Edge but it says I got the newest version, I tried updating and changing default browser to Chrome, but I get the same error. Never seen this type before and don't know what to do next, cant see any resembling threads on the VS forums.